# Please help identify this bathroom faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing-fixture, usa, cartridge

I'm trying to fix a leaky faucet cartridge in my bathroom, but I'm unable to identify what brand it is to order a replacement. Couldn't find a brand name anywhere.

**Could someone please help me identify which brand this is? Even better which exact model?**

This is in the US, WA state more precisely. I *think* that it's about 4 or 5 years old, but not 100% sure.

Pictures below - the measuring tape on the pictures is in inches.

[image: trying to identify this one]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best bet is to usually take it to a local plumbing/hardware shop.  They can usually match it up in no time and get you the right part.

Comment: Bring it to plumbing store, or clean the surfaces and look for a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

[image]

DANCO  3G-3H Hot Stem for Price Pfister Faucets

https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-3G-3H-Hot-Stem-for-Price-Pfister-Faucets-18864B/202832807#overlay

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly it :)